# What does "NOT SUPPORTED" mean?

Tags: system-installation

When I ran the DVD for installing Ubuntu 12.04 (32 bit) - needed "Install CD boot helper" and after clicking "Install and Demo" and  re-boot a message is displayed "NOT SUPPORTED". I'm running my computer with Windows XP Home (32 bit).  I'm able to run the the Demo version of Ubuntu.  I then installed Ubuntu on a separate partition (30GB) to XP which seemed to be successful because I could get on line and try the various programmes successfully. On exiting from Ubuntu the scene went black and subsequent attempts to re-boot Ubuntu & XP failed. Re-booting with Ubuntu didn't give access to the installed programme but could access as a guest.   To get XP working again I had to format the hard disc and re-install XP."

Was "NOT SUPPORTED" a warning that I could't run Ubuntu on my computer? If so why?

Answer (score 0):

Was there not more to the message?  Like "Frequency not supported"?  Was it in a box centered in the middle of the screen?  If so then that's your monitor complaining that it doesn't support the resolution the video card is trying to drive it in.